# Check as CRAN, but do not skip any tests

Tags: r, devtools, cran, testthat

Is there any easy way with `devtools::check()` to run the [extended CRAN checks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10017736) but also run testhat tests that are marked as `skip_on_cran()`?

Basically, I want to run the most comprehensive tests I can: all of the CRAN checks, plus all of my unit tests

Comment: Shouldn't tests marked `skip_on_cran` run locally? Doesn't the param `cran=TRUE` in `devtools::check()` do `--as-cran`?

Answer (score 0):

The current version of `testhat::skip_on_cran` just check a system variable:

```
testthat::skip_on_cran
function () 
{
    if (identical(Sys.getenv("NOT_CRAN"), "true")) {
        return(invisible(TRUE))
    }
    skip("On CRAN")
}
```

On my site, the `devtools::check` does not set this environment variable even with `cran = TRUE` so all tests are run. That is, the question does not seem to make sense with the present version of `testthat`.